# Need to parse error object from the given message coming from third party API in java Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 4

Tags: java, string, parsing

```
400 Bad Request: [{"error":{"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"username must be of 8 characters.","source":null,"step":null,"reason":"input_validation_failed","metadata":{},"field":"name"}}]
```

When i am integrating with third party API. API is sending me the bad request error. Want to get Error object from the following message

When I am trying it with

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
com.model.Error err = gson.fromJson(str, com.model.Error.class);
```

Getting following error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 4
```

Not able to understand why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

> **[** -> begin JSONArray **{** -> begin JSONObject

**Error err -> object** So it must start with a symbol **{** ,  but **400 Bad Request: **[**{"error":..}]** begin with symbol array **[**

modify the beginning of the request to object symbol :

```
{
  "code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
  "description":"username must be of 8 characters.",
  "source":null,
  "step":null,
  "reason":"input_validation_failed",
  "metadata":{},
  "field":"name"
}
```